# Image rotated 90 degrees in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jpeg

When I view a photo I took using my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 using Windows Photo Viewer, the image is oriented correctly.

However, when I scp it to my website, it's rotated 90 degrees when viewed in Chrome, but displays correctly in firefox. The image in question is this one: http://drazzy.com/e/espruino/etc/20140925_152033.jpg

Why doesn't it display correctly in Chrome? How can I make my images display correctly in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine is displayed being rotated 90 degrees for both Chrome and Firefox for me. Find the original picture and open it on your computer. Depending on how you took it, the phones accelerometer may have simply registered a different rotation when you took the picture. Open it in paint, select the picture as a whole, and rotate is 90 degrees counter clock wise.